# Why X(X&) could be called for two times?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I wrote this code:

```
    struct X{
        int val;

        void out(const string& s, int nv)
            {cerr<<this<<"->"<<s<<": "<<val<<"("<<nv<<")\n";}

        X() {out("X(int)",0); val=0;}
        X(int v){out("X(int)",v); val=v;}
        X(const X& x){out("X(X&)",x.val); val=x.val;}
        X& operator=(const X& a)
            {out("X::operator=()",a.val); val=a.val; return *this;}
        ~X() {out("~X()",0);}
    };

    X copy(X a) {return a;}

    int main{
        X loc2;
        X loc(5);
        loc2 = copy(loc);
        return 0;
    }
```

The output is this(in VS2010):

```
003BFAA0->X(int): -858993460(0)
003BFA94->X(int): -858993460(5)
003BF964->X(X&): 723486321(5)
003BF994->X(X&): -858993460(5)
003BF964->~X(): 5(0)
003BFAA0->X::operator=(): 0(5)
003BF994->~X(): 5(0)
```

The first two lines are fine. But the third and fourth lines show that it calls X(X&) two times. The copy(X a) has only one "X a" in it. Why X(X&) could be called for two times?

Answer (score 6):

> **Why `X(X&)` could be called for two times?**

With the function call:

```
loc2 = copy(loc);
```

`copy(loc);` calls copy constructor two times:

1. To create copy of argument `loc` being passed to the function.
2. To create copy of return object `a`.

In C/C++ arguments to functions are ***passed by value*** by default. So not the actual argument but the copy of the passed object/variable is recieved in the function call.This copy is created by calling the copy constructor.
Your `copy()` function also ***returns by value*** again resulting in copy constructor being called.

Note that in certain instances the compiler might elide(remove) calls to copy constructor and construct the objects inline, the phenomenon is known as **Copy Elision**.In general you should'nt write any code which produces side effects based on number of times the copy constructor is being called.

Answer (score 1):

When "return a" gets executed, copy of object of type X gets created because return type is X (not X&). (Had it been X& - it would also have been an error - Formal argument of copy function "a" is a variable with local scope)